# Can the context menu be changed dynamically?

Tags: tabulator

Is it possible to change the context menu dynamically, once the tabulator table is already built?
I need to change the context menu according to the cell value under the mouse cursor, so if I could somehow change the context menu inside the `cellMouseOver` callback, that would be great.

Thanks,
Matic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of specifying a menu object, what you want is a [Menu Items Generator Function](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/menu#overview-generator). The example on that page shows returning one menu if `approved` is false and a different menu if `approved` is true.

Comment: How did I miss that? Excellent, thank you!